# ios - Could not cast value of type 'TestApplication.ViewControllerResultat' to 'TestApplication.ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide'

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a viewcontroller in a viewcontroller.

When I try to call the the second viewcontroller in my override func prepare function, i get Could not cast value of type-error

My code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let ViewControllerResultatet : ViewControllerResultat = segue.destination as! ViewControllerResultat

    ViewControllerResultatet.LabelTextEben = "\(count)"

        if count >= 22
        {
           ViewControllerResultatet.labelBestaaet = "Tillykke du har bestået prøven!"
        }
        else
        {
            ViewControllerResultatet.labelBestaaet = "Du dumpede desværre prøven"
        }


        let ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide : ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide = segue.destination as! ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide

        ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide.LabelTextTilSpoergsmaal = Questions[QNumber].Question


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two different segues, and two different `UIViewController` subclasses.  In your `prepare(for segue: sender:)` function you aren't checking which segue is being invoked and you have two different forced downcasts.  One of these will fail and throw an exception for the "other" segue.

You can check the value of the `segue.identifier` to see which segue was performed, or you can use a conditional downcast to see which view controller you are dealing with, or both.  You haven't given your segue identifiers, so I will show the second approach:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewControllerResultatet : ViewControllerResultat = segue.destination as? ViewControllerResultat {

        viewControllerResultatet.LabelTextEben = "\(count)"

        if count >= 22
        {
           viewControllerResultatet.labelBestaaet = "Tillykke du har bestået prøven!"
        }
        else
        {
           viewControllerResultatet.labelBestaaet = "Du dumpede desværre prøven"
        }
    } else if let viewControllerForkertKorrektSide : ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide = segue.destination as? ViewControllerForkertKorrektSide {

        viewControllerForkertKorrektSide.LabelTextTilSpoergsmaal = Questions[QNumber].Question
    }
}
```

I would suggest, however, that your `prepare` function should just set an integer `count` property on the destination view controller and the logic that sets the labels should be in *that* view controller.